# Prediction error without having a true value

Tags: machine-learning, regression, predictive-modeling, xgboost, accuracy

Quick summary about the problem: we are trying to deploy our regression model, where the clients require "individual prediction error". Since we're predicting something unknown in advance, we can't measure the error the standard way of `y_true - y_predicted`.

I have done some research already, but the problems with existing methods are this:

- Since we're using boosting algorithms (xgboost, catboost), we can't
  rely on normality assumptions and generate standard confidence
  intervals.
- A solution proposed [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25443/prediction-intervals-using-xgboost) is to train multiple models and get the
  average of it, but then it's not viable in the production level as it
  would become at least 3 times as slow to train / predict.
- Another way is to create a quantile regression as stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255783/confidence-interval-for-xgb-forecast),
  but this would impact our accuracy, which we can't sacrifice.
- Finally, we have tried to train a model using our validation set error and try to predict the test set error, but the accuracy is very very low.

So my question is this: **Is there a way to estimate an individual prediction error, without knowing it's true value in advance, that wouldn't affect the model accuracy or speed?**

Comment: What do you mean by individual prediction error? Is it like say my model predict $\hat{y}$ then you are supposed to output how "confident" it is?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Is linear model enough? Have you read about bayesian linear regression?

Comment: That's the problem - our main goal is to be as accurate as possible and linear models just aren't as accurate (although much more explainable). We haven't ran the bayesian regression though, I will definitely check it out.

Comment: This is a good article https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-prediction-intervals-with-xgboost-428e0a018b

Comment: Thanks - it's an interesting approach! I've tried implementing it, but it dropped the accuracy by quite a great margin :\